# A Play 1.x app randomly loses the reference to any of its view templates

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I've been working with Play 1.x for almost 2 years now, and this is the first time I am experiencing something like this. My app keeps running on the server (in production mode), and after a certain period of time, it just "hangs"

When a particular path gets called, I see an "internal error" message. When I inspect the logs, I see the following all over:

```
@6j3jc3f0p
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /action/4343206

Template not found (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 206)
The template Application/action.html does not exist.

play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : MyController/showDetails.html
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:668)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:641)
    at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:696)
    at controllers.MyController.showDetails(MyController.java:206)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
14:32:50,665 ERROR ~ 

@6j3jc3f10
Error during the 500 response generation

Template not found
The template errors/500.html does not exist.

play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : errors/500.html
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:192)
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:774)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

Looks, as if after some time, the application loses any point of reference to its templates, even the default one that is responsible for opening up when there is a 500 error.

I googled around and found out that this may be due to the way the code is compiled. I am running under java version `1.7.0_60`. Another application that I've been running successfully for a couple of months now is running on java version `1.7.0_51`, and `java.source=1.5`. When I tried to set java.source to 1.5 here, I could not even compile the code, so I set it to 1.6, but as it seems, this is not helping much either.

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong? It can't be anything in the code, as it is based on the code base of the application that has been running continuously for months in production.

Comment: Which Play version is this? Nothing jumps out from the stacktrace, so I'm not sure what is going wrong, but I am intrigued by the fact it lists two different controllers and their methods, with one being called and executing and the other throwing the root exception...

Comment: @gpgekko this is Play 1.2.5

Comment: One thing you could do to confirm if Play lost reference to its templates is adding a log statement / break point and see if `Play.templatesPath` is empty or not. This should contain the root paths (`app/views/`) for the application and any modules, and is used in the template lookup / loading code.

Comment: If `Play.templatesPath` is not empty and the entries seem sensible, my best guess would be that the actual folder structure for your templates is off. Can you confirm that `showDetails.html` is indeed at the expected location (`app/views/MyController/showDetails.html`)? Also, are `Application.java` and `MyController.java` the same thing? If not, could you post both the class definition and the indicated line in the stacktrace (206) for both files?